Reference images and image texture have turned purple
The Blender project has been saved to a USB, and then opened on a different workstation. Now the reference images and image textures, which were also placed on the same USB, are showing as bright pink in Blender

this is always the case, if Blender doesn't find the image texture at the location it would have expected them. A "usual" mistake is, when you didn't do "pack resources" before saving your blend file.

...or you should have made the path relative to the blend file path. In the Preferences under Save & Load > Blend Files set Default to Relative Paths. And for this project, to find the missing textures and reconnect with the current paths go to File > External Data > Find Missing Files, then choose the directory on the USB where the textures are.
